# Redirecting all subdomains to one page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm trying to redirect all subdomains at `(http://*.domain.com)` to spesific html file `(http://domain.com/index.html)`. But I also want to visible subdomain name won't change.

I've tried this one with .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/parent/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L]
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subdomains are a bit different than directories. You need to have a [wildcard DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) to catch all subdomains:

```
*.example.com. 3600 IN  A host1.example.com.
```

Best thing to do would be to contact your hosting provider. Some of them have settings to achieve that.

Comment: Oh. My hosting provider clearly stated that they don't support wildcards. Thanks anyway.